# Executar arquivo NodeJS a partir de um link ou botão HTML

Tags: node.js, login, async-await, puppeteer

Olá, sou novo em NodeJS e executar um código que utiliza Puppeteer para abrir um site e realizar login, isso já consigo fazer, agora preciso criar uma forma para disponibilizar esse código de forma que seja acessível via link ou botão HTML, segue o código de minha aplicação.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  //Acessa a pagina de login da biblioteca
  await page.goto('https://sitequeseraacessado.com');
  
  //Clica no botao para aceitar todos os cookies
  await page.click('[class="cookies-policy-accept-button"]');

  //Insere os dados de login
  await page.type('[name="userIdTextBox"]', 'usuario');
  await page.type('[name="passwordTextBox"]', 'senha');

  //Clica no botao de login
  await page.click('[name="loginButton"]');

})();
```

Como dito antes este código já funciona, o que desejo agora é uma maneira de executar a partir de um botão HTML ou link.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.